# Multiple models compared over same data

Tags: nonparametric, multiple-comparisons

My question boils down to if I really have to use a multiple comparison adjustment or not, and if so, how I can do this to retain as much power as possible.

I have multiple models (say 5) that are scored on how well they match up to data over cross fold validation.  Since the score that is used (area under an ROC curve) is not sampled from a normal distribution, I used a nonparametric Wilcoxon signed rank test to compare the models to each other over each fold.  I want to be able to report which models are significantly different from each other while preserving the most power.

If my problem involved finding which factor was relevant for a given disease (going fishing), I know I definitely have to do a multiple comparison adjustment.  However, each test that I'm doing is a "local" test, only indicating whether model A is significantly different than model B.  If I had 100 models, the number of comparisons would be huge, but I don't think the p-values should be weakened, because the claim would still be limited to just differences between Model X and Model Y.  Because of this, I don't think I have to adjust for it.  However, I can't find justification for this in a book or paper anywhere.

If I'm wrong, I want to use Holm-Bonferroni since this is nonparametric and that seems to be the best fit, but there might be a better choice here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in practice, people routinely use Newman-Keuls or Tukey methods to test a family of pairwise differences of means in  the parametric normal case. That seems similar to your situation-- am I mistaken? So I think a multiplicity adjustment is called for.

The Holm method does sound like a good choice; it offers "FDR" type control like Newman-Keuls does.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Wilcoxon test at all: it assumes random sampling, and you are doung cross-validation. Maybe you should use something like 5×2 cv F-test (see Alpaydm, E. (1999). Combined 5 × 2 cv F Test for Comparing Supervised Classification Learning Algorithms. Neural Computation, 11(8), 1885–1892).